# Conectarse a una base de datos mysql en java usando JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Tengo este codigo para conectar una base de datos con java pero no me funciona nada, e investigado en muchas partes y nomas no encuentro solucion, aqui el codigo:

```
public void pruebaConexion(){
Connection con;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blenprueba","root","");
        Toast mensaje= Toast.makeText(this, "conectado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mensaje.show();
    con.close();

} 

catch(Exception e)
{
Toast mensaje= Toast.makeText(this, "Error de conec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
mensaje.show();
}


}
```

Nose que mas hace, si alguien mas sabe como puedo arreglarlo porfavor ayudeme

Estas son las librerias que tengo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da exactamente?

Comment: deberías añadir `e.printStackTrace();` dentro del bloque catch y ver qué falla

Comment: JDev, el problema es que no se conecta la base de datos con el programa, al iniciar el emulador me manda directo al catch y aparece el toast diciendo "error de conec", cuando lo que yo quiero que haga es que me mande el mensaje "conectado correctamente" pero no se que problema tengo, talvez alguna libreria mal, una parte de codigo mal nose, porfavor si sabes como solucinarlo mencionamelo.

Comment: Por el código veo que es una aplicación Android. ¿Dónde has instalado el jar del jdbc de mysql?

Comment: Te da "error de conec" por que lo tienes literalmente en el catch, eso no significa que sea error de conexión. Deberías de capturar la excepción como comenta @Pabo Lozano

Comment: OscarGarcia, si te refieres al conector tengo uno que es "MySQL-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar" y lo tengo en la carpeta de libs de el proyecto, si no te refieres a eso, perdon pero es que soy principiante

Comment: Y también tienes una BD MySQL instalada en el emulador? Lo dudo mucho. Instala la BD en algún hosting gratuito y conecta por IP, no utilizes *localhost*. Y, como ya te han dicho, pon un **statckTrace** para ver qué error te da.

Comment: Apoyo lo dicho por @EvgeniEnchev, la cadena de conexión `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blenprueba` está intentando conectarse a un servidor MySQL que se está ejecutando en el mismo móvil en el que ejecutas la aplicación, cosa que veo poco probable. Deberás cambiar `localhost` por el nombre o IP del servidor MySQL y, además, deberías agregar el mensaje de la excepción al toast para conocer más detalles del error y en vez de usar el `e.printStackTrace()` que te han recomendado, usar `Log.e("tuclase", "excepción", e)` y así poder revisar el problema en el logcat.

Comment: Lo del toast lo puedes hacer así: `Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Comment: como poder te puedes conectar a localhost, si tienes la base de datos en local, con phpmyadmin puedes montar un base de datos de local Mysql, prueba en vez de poner locahost la ip local que es 127.0.0.1 , com dicen pon para ver el mesaje de error que te da y con eso podras ver algo mejor en que te esta fallando

Comment: si estas desde android, en el emulador la ip que tienes que poner es '10.0.2.2'

Comment: La API de JDBC para conectarte a las bases de datos no funciona correctamente en Androido y hay casos en los que simplemente falla, ten encenta que aun que Android utiliza java no es 100% compatible con todo lo que existe, la forma correcta de acceder es creando un proyecto java que se conecte a la base de datos y exponga la información por  medio de servicio REST, no se le a dado importancia por parte del desarrollo Android porque no es recomendable que el mobil se conecte directamente la base de datos limitarías el numero de usuario demasiado según la base de datos hasta 500 conexiones.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos los que me apoyaron, al iniciar el programa ahora me sale "conectado correctamente" creo que ya agarro, muchas gracias les debo la vida (jesus cabrera, puse la ip que me dijiste y asi me funciono, gracias)

Answer (score 0):

yo tambien tuve ese problema y es muy tedioso.

```
public class Conexion {

    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Proyecto?autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false";
       // En la parte de Proyecto va el nombre de tu base de datos jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**Proyecto?**
    public static final String Usuario ="root"; //Usuario con el que tienes registrado tu base de datos
    public static final String Contraseña = ""; //Contraseña con la que tienes registrada tu base de datos

    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conexion=null;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Usuario, Contraseña);
        // Ventana para verificar que esta conectado.    
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error,"+ex);
        }

        return conexion;
    }
}
```

Si el problema no es la conexion pueden ser los siguientes
1. Que no esta encendida la base de datos
2. Que no estas poniendo bien la ruta hacia la base de datos

Estos son los errores mas comunes que a mi me sucedieron, espero te sirva el codigo y la respuesta, saludos!.